# Can I render an image with json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, render

I'm using Typeahead to render instances of my "User" model in a drop-down list:

**Controller:**

```
def typeahead
  render json: User.where(name: params[:query])
end
```

**View:**

```
<input type="text" id="typeahead">
<script type="text/javascript">
  var bloodhound = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) {
      return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

    remote: '/typeahead/%QUERY', 
    limit: 50
  });
  bloodhound.initialize();

  $('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'name',
    source: bloodhound.ttAdapter()
  });

  $('#typeahead').bind('typeahead:selected', function(event, datum, name) {
    doSomething(datum.id);
  });
</script>
```

This code causes a list of `User.name`s to drop down as I type.

Can I render an image, in this case `User.avatar.url(:thumb)`? When I change `displayKey: 'name',` to `displayKey: 'avatar.url(:thumb)',` the drop-down list simply says "undefined" for every User.

[I made sure that `User.avatar.url(:thumb)` displays successfully elsewhere]

Comment: Your javascript is not interpreting ruby. It is accessing the `name` key on the returned json. If you want to be able to use the `avatar`, you'll to see how it is included in the json. Assuming `paperclip`, you'd have a `avatar_file_name` key, but I'm not familiar enough with `typeahead` to tell you how to turn that filename into an image to display in your javascript.

Comment: @ptd Do you think it's possible at least?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode the image as base64 on your server, then return the resulting string in your json response, and finally on the client side use this base64 string to populate your image

**1-** server side: encode image as base64

```
def typeahead
  users = User.where(name: params[:query])

  json = users.collect do |user|
    path = user.avatar.url(:thumb)
    image = open(path) { |io| io.read }
    base64 = ActiveSupport::Base64.encode64(image)

    {id: user.id, name: user.name, base64: base64}
  end

  render json: json
end
```

**2-** Client side: use templating to populate users name and image

```
$('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  displayKey: 'name',
  source: bloodhound.ttAdapter()
  templates: {
    suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,{{base64}}">{{name}}</p>')
  }
});
```

Note1: not tested, you may have to do little adjustments

Note2: This will require a lot of power from your server when you have a big users table and a lot of concurrent connections, because the server would have to open and encode many image files for each query.

Answer (score 2):

The `displayKey` attribute tells Typeahead which (string) field of the *JSON response* to show, thus it can only point to an existing JSON attribute, e.g. `name`.

I would suggest not rendering the image and instead providing its URL as part of the response, and then rendering it in the browser.

For example, you could add a new method to your `User` model:

```
def thumb_url
  avatar.url(:thumb)
end
```

Add that method's result to your controller's response:

```
def typeahead
  render json: User.where(name: params[:query]), methods: :thumb_url
end
```

And then use the response in a [Typeahead template](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#custom-templates) instead of `displayKey`, e.g.

```
$('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  source: bloodhound.ttAdapter()
  templates: {
    suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p><img src="{{thumb_url}}">{{name}}</p>')
  }
});
```

(Note that you'd have to add [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) for this to work.)